# How to make the subtitle (a or b) of an image position correctly?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subdividing, subcaption

I want the following subtitles (a or b) to be shown correctly not like the current view as shown in the following image:
[image]

Also how can I add more spacing between the two images?

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure [a] {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lap1.png}}\quad
  \subfigure [b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lap2.png}}
  \hfill
  \caption { (a) A ring graph (b) Its Laplacian matrix}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: (1) What does 'correctly' mean in this context? (2) The `\quad` is controlling the between-figure spacing, so you can use something else if you want more (or less) space between the two figures.  Also: a complete minimal working example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are using `subfigure` package which is obsolete. Use either `subcaption` package that provides `subfigure` environment or `subfig` package which gives `subfloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption { (a) A ring graph (b) Its Laplacian matrix}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]